# Django order_by('?')[:n] n using a variable which I take from the database? but not work

Tags: django, python-3.x, sql-order-by

```
def home (request):
questions = Article.objects.order_by('?')

n = guestionNum.objects.all()
n = n[0]

answers = Answer.objects.all().order_by('?')[:n]

return render_to_response('question/home.html', {'questions': questions, 'answers': answers,'n':n, 'username':auth.get_user(request).username}) `
```

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'guestionNum' and 'int'

How do I make a slice using a variable n which I take from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = guestionNum.objects.all()
n = n[0]
```

you cant slice because the above line returns an instance not int object

try

```
n = guestionNum.objects.all()
n=n[0].fieldname
```

then pass it to the slice

Comment: How can I do this? n take values from the model: {class guestionNum (models.Model):
    question_num = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_num}

Comment: try len(n) and print(n) to check what it returns? and what do you mean by takes value from model?

Comment: in db set 5 ...and print 5

Comment: TypeError
Exception Value:  

object of type 'guestionNum' has no len()

Comment: print n = 1  but in db set number 5 аnd I want to make a slice on the variable which is an index in the database and is equal to 5

Comment: What is set to 5? Do you have a field which is having the value 5?

Comment: Yes a field which is having the value 5. n = guestionNum.objects.all()
    #n = n[0] ( n having value 5)

Comment: No you have to use n[0].fieldname to get the value. Try it

Comment: Haha. No problem bro. Glad could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
n = guestionNum.objects.all()
n = n[0]
# n == guestionNum.objects.first()  // Both have same type and data
```

Now type of `n` is instance not queryset.

So you can use direct n value from below code.

```
n = guestionNum.objects.first().fieldname
```